# Magento 1.7 Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory Sometimes Only

Tags: mysql, magento-1.7

**Cause:** Magento 1.7 Site (front end as well as admin panel) suddenly started throwing errors of below two. Sometimes first error, sometimes second error and that too in 25% of times. Rest of the time site working fine without any issue.

> error 1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>  error 2:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] MYSQL server gone away

**Solution Tried:** 
1. changed time out and socket variable in my.cnf file
2. changed directory to tmp
all possible solution done

My confusion is, it happened only sometimes.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your server not Magento. You should to check the your server logs (I prefer start from the MySQL).